# Passing variables from a activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent

I try to send a variable from a activity to another but i get an error.I am using this because i want to send some data about each item of a menu to another activity and then modify the text views according to the data received. I've attached only one information that i want to sent which is the title..
I've attached my activities and the LogCat error:

**MainActivity**

```
        Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Title", lessons_titles[position]);                                  

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Example1.class);

        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

**Passing Activity**

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String title = bundle.getString("Title");                           
    title_view.setText(title);
```

**LogCat Error**

```
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to    instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.Example1}:   java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.example.test.Example1.<init>(Example1.java:10)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
03-12 17:18:31.529: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     ... 11 more
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.Example1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at   android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at com.example.test.Example1.<init>(Example1.java:10)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
03-12 17:21:55.112: E/AndroidRuntime(2031):     ... 11 more
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.Example1}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at  android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at com.example.test.Example1.<init>(Example1.java:10)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
03-12 17:22:02.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2050):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is at line 10 of Example1.java? It looks like you may be calling findViewById from your constructor before calling setContentView, which is not valid. The Activity view hasn't been setup yet.

Comment: TextView title_view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.titleView);

Comment: Where are you calling this code from? `onCreate()`, `onResume()`? Provide more details. The code itself is not incorrect, but there are other things around it that need to be considered like `Activity life-cycle`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `findViewById` from your Activity constructor. You can't call `findViewById` until after the Activity view has been set by calling `setContentView` which should be done in `onCreate`. For example:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public MyActivity() {
        // Do not do anything with views here
    }

    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
        // Now you can do stuff with your views
        final TextView title_view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.titleView);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I found the mistake and you are right. thanks again:)